# React Native - GooglePlacesAutocomplete search location by cordinaats

Tags: react-native

I am currently searching for a location with GooglePlacesAutocomplete. I am currently searching for a location by name of the location. I also want to search based on the coordinates of the location. For example, instead of searching: I want to type the coordinates 37.869160, 32.461850 and search. I want to search both by coordinates and by the name of the location

```
 <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                    placeholder="Bir Konum Arayın"
                    GooglePlacesDetailsQuery={{ fields: 'geometry' }}
                    fetchDetails={true}
                    onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                      console.log("sa1dsad", details)
                      this.setState({
                        region: {
                          latitude: details.geometry.location.lat,
                          longitude: details.geometry.location.lng,
                          latitudeDelta: 0.002,
                          longitudeDelta: 0.002,
                        }
                      })
                    }}
                    query={{ key: "...", language: 'tr' }}
                  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is reverse geocoding. Google places API provides this, but the `GooglePlacesAutocomplete` would not allow you to use it directly.

You can setup this library: https://github.com/marlove/react-native-geocoding

If you follow the usage example, you should be able to populate a list using the returned values.

```
// Search by geo-location (reverse geo-code)
Geocoder.from(41.89, 12.49)
        .then(json => {
                var addressComponent = json.results[0].address_components[0];
            console.log(addressComponent);
        })
        .catch(error => console.warn(error));
```